# Did The Joker win the psychological battle over Batman in The Dark Knight?

Tags: analysis, the-dark-knight

I have watched the movie *The Dark Knight* many times. However, I still ponder who won the final psychological battle between Batman and The Joker.

I understand that The Joker failed to deliver on his "these civilized people will eat each other" belief, as the people on the ship didn't detonate the bomb. Also he failed to corrupt Batman. But on the other hand, he managed to transform Harvey Dent and created a huge anarchy.

So the question is, who really won this battle over the soul of Gotham? And what would be the evidence? Does the movie give a definite answer on that or support a specific viewpoint on who won there or is it deliberately left open?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is too much within the context of personal opinion and isn't supported enough by content from the film. If the OP can reform the question to validate/explain the existence of "the psychological battle" and how/why there could be an actual outcome to the battle, I think it'd stand a higher chance of being answered and not closed.

Comment: I tried to rephrase the question a little and removed some of the asker's assumptive wording which was likely the cause for the close-votes.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. @NapoleonWilson

Comment: Since this was the Joker's debut, I'd say the war had only just begun - the only reason it had not continued is because of Heath Ledger's untimely end. You simply couldn't replace him after that performance.